# Linux-kernel: make isoimage fails due to missing certs. Proceed how?

Tags: linux-kernel, makefile, x509certificate, archlinux, iso-image

I tried **make isoimage** but got:

---

```
kernel/Makefile:135: *** No X.509 certificates found ***

CHK     kernel/config_data.h
Kernel: arch/x86/boot/bzImage is ready  (#1)
rm -rf arch/x86/boot/isoimage
mkdir arch/x86/boot/isoimage
for i in lib lib64 share end ; do \
    if [ -f /usr/$i/syslinux/isolinux.bin ] ; then \
            cp /usr/$i/syslinux/isolinux.bin arch/x86/boot/isoimage ; \
               [...]
done
arch/x86/boot/Makefile:160: rule for target „isoimage“ failed
make[1]: *** [isoimage] error 1
arch/x86/Makefile:236: rule for target „isoimage“ failed
make: *** [isoimage] error 2
```

---

while using AUR build system.

So where does one get those certs from and where to put them?

Comment: Possibly the problem is unrelated to certs, but I got no other error msg.

Comment: beyond the stated ones, that was to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on Arch-Linux & derivates, the certs will be put in place by:

pacman -S linux

That linux package should have "mkisolinux" as a dependency, because the

make isoimage

requires it. Still, one needs to manually copy

cp /usr/lib/syslinux/bios/isolinux.bin /usr/include/syslinux/isolinux.bin

for the target to actually succeed.

"make isoimage" does work after these measures usually.

The issue is reproducible and could be easily fixed in Arch.

Comment: the iso thus created does not fully boot, but stops with an error message about missing ld32  :-(